# For Loop Isn't Working

Tags: java, for-loop

I am testing a for-loop for smoothly moving an object on the screen.

```
int yPosLeft = 339;
int originalYPosLeft = yPosLeft;

for(yPosLeft < 30 + originalYPosLeft; yPosLeft++) {
// Changes the value in the statement
}
```

However, the loop somehow makes the object's y position go into the negative millions forever and pretty much requires a force quit. Any suggestions?

**Update:** I was stupid with this. Apologies for #BrainFart #Fixed

Comment: some crazy chit here

Comment: Stupid questions do not exist, but this one is getting very close

Comment: Lol `yPosLeft < 30 + yPosLeft` and `yPosLeft = yPosLeft`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition is:

```
yPosLeft < 30 + yPosLeft
```

...which will always be true. A value will always be less than 30 plus that same value.

Hence, the loop will continue forever and your object's y position will move forever! (That is, until `yPosLeft` gets so big that it overflows - but I seriously doubt that's the desired behaviour.)

Comment: This loop doesn't run forever. It will terminate (after a looooooooooong time).

Answer (score 3):

Every number will **always** be inferior than itself + any positive number. So the condition is always evaluated to true, and hence your loop runs forever.

You need to rework your loop. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: This loop doesn't run forever. It will terminate (after a looooooooooong time).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant:

```
int yPosLeft = 339;

for(int i = yPosLeft; i > yPosLeft - 30; i--) {
// Changes the value in the statement
}
```

but I'm not an Oracle ;) - just guessing

Comment: @Downvoter he doesn't deserve -1 anymore. This is quite possibly the answer the OP was looking for.